# How to regex a string - length 10, first three character letter and remaining numeric

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a regex to find if first three letters are character and the remaining letters are number. The total length of the words is 10.

Comment: What do you mean by "character"? Letters only? Or, maybe, letters and digits? Or any non-whitespace?

Comment: I googling Java regex and got here. My string is length 20, I need first 5 characters, but so what? I can replace {3} with {5}! Soup Nazis, why did you close this question??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `"^[a-zA-Z]{3}\\d{7}$"`?

Comment: No need of those anchors.

Answer (score 4):

Let's try something like this :

`[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{7}`

You can eventually replace the digit part (`[0-9]`) with the metacharacter `\d` in Java :

`[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{7}`

Personaly, I don't like this version because I find it less explicit that the previous one.
`\w` wont replace exactly the alpha part, as it correspond to `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`.

If you need to capture some part, use the bracket. Exemple for capturing the three first letters :

`([a-zA-Z]{3})[0-9]{7}`

I would recommand you to learn the use of regex through a tutorial. It's a powerful tool that most developer should know.

Answer (score 1):

the regex will looks like this(in its simplest form):

```
[a-zA-Z]{3}[\d]{7}
```

The rest depends on what exactly do you want to achieve..

Comment: This would also match the string `0123456789`. `\w` denotes a word character `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`.

Comment: @devnull you are right

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to look at this page:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/

Alternatively type "java 6" (or 7) API.

Go to method compare of the Class java.util.String and from there follow the ling or go directly to class java.util.regex.Pattern